# Can I code to control the mechanical mechanisms of a phone?

Tags: video, interactive

It is possible to write a line of code that would initiate the vibration motor within a phone. App developers are able to do this. But, is it possible to have that code be paired with a video, so that the phone vibrates to certain points of a film? For example, if I took a video of an explosion, could I write a line of code that would trigger the  vibration motor at the same time stamp of the explosion? Would this video be able to be exported to an mp4, mov, or h264 format and posted to social networks?

Comment: So I’ve realized what I’m talking about is called haptics. I would like the code to work for both. But how would that be integrated to video? And How would I be able to share the video file. Would the code be permanently engrained in the video? Thank you.

Comment: I also realize this would need to be done in xcode/swift. But how do I integrate it with video? Would I have to design an entire app for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to design an app for this to work, yeah.  Tinder launched a video series a while back called Swipe Night that did this, the haptics were called from inside the application.